# How to split the string with multiple Delimiters and restrict the split after restrict splitting after the certain delimiter in C#

Tags: c#, split

I need to split string with a {space}, {double space}, and {"}

```
string details = 12/08/2020 12:01:00 AM  This is first line  to  split  "Do Not Split This."
```

I need to get an array of strings with :

01/01/2020
12:01:00 AM
This
is
first
line
to
split
Do Not Split This.

Any help ?

I have tried by using string.split()

```
string[] mystrings = details.Split(' ','"'),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I am able to split with {' '} single space in the string, I was stuck on how to restric the split after quote {"}.

Comment: Why in your example `This is first line` and `Do Not Split This.` not split into words? There is a space delimiter

Comment: Hi sir @SergeyBerezovskiy  **Do Not Split This.**  which is in the Quotes I need to get it  as one string.

Comment: Probably need to use regex

Comment: You might be able to split first by ", and then split the even indexed results by space. But it might be easier to just write a simple parser that processes the string character by character. Regex might also be possible, but regex is somewhat notoriously difficult to read.

Comment: @JonasH Thank you, I am able to split by " first and removing empty entries from the first half and splitting with space.